Numbers with a given Pisano period
From some experimentation, it appears that the largest $n$ with Pisano period $2k$ is (starting with $k=3$): $4, 3, 11, 8, 29, 21, 76, 55, 199, \ldots$, which matches OEIS A005013 (and also that smaller such $n$ divide the largest one). The tables of Pisano periods of Fibonacci and Lucas numbers in the Wikipedia article on Pisano periods shows that the reverse implication is true - that the Pisano period of $a(n)$ is $2n$.
Is this a known fact? Can anyone provide a reference? I've been unable to make much progress on proving this.
